# IllegalArgumentException while calling the Encryptors of spring-security-crypto in test

Tags: java, junit, spring-security

I am trying to write a JUnit test case for the below code. I am using Encryptors of the spring-security-crypto library. When I am trying to run the code I am able to successfully to encrypt the string but when I am running the test case I am getting an error.

code

```java
public String standardEncryption(String value) {
        if (!isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
            return Encryptors.text(password, salt).encrypt(value);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Junit test case

```java
@Test
    public void can_standardEncryption() {
        String value = someNumericString(10);

        String result = encryption.standardEncryption(value);

        assertThat(result).isNotNull();
        assertThat(result.equals(value)).isFalse();
        assertThat(textEncryptor.decrypt(result)).isEqualTo(value);
        assertThat(result.equals(textEncryptor.encrypt(value))).isFalse();
    }
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to initialize due to invalid secret key

    at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils.initCipher(CipherUtils.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.AesBytesEncryptor.encrypt(AesBytesEncryptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.HexEncodingTextEncryptor.encrypt(HexEncodingTextEncryptor.java:36)
    at something(something.java:25)
    at something(something.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1039)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1396)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils.initCipher
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might need to enable larger key sizes.

By default, Spring Security creates a 256-bit AES key, based on the password that you provide. However, Java 8 doesn't allow keys of this size by default.

If you are *earlier than Java 8u151*, then you need to [download a jar](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) and add it to your installation, replacing what's in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security` with what you download.

If you are on *Java 8u151 or later*, then this policy jar is shipped by default, but needs to be enabled by uncommenting the following line in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`:

```
crypto.policy=unlimited
```

Or, I believe OpenJDK has this enabled by default, so you could also switch out your JVM.

Source: https://github.com/open-eid/cdoc4j/wiki/Enabling-Unlimited-Strength-Jurisdiction-Policy

Comment: So you asume OP uses a different Java version when running the code (where he wrote it works) and when he runs the unit tests?

Comment: @jzheaux I am getting error java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.nextSpi(SecretKeyFactory.java:295)
 at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(SecretKeyFactory.java:121)
 at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
 at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:89)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot locate policy or framework files!
 at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:256)

Comment: @Tom, that`s what assume that the java version is same but I am getting an error while running test.

Comment: Just to add I am using jdk1.8.0_101 but when I am using JDK version jdk1.8.0_171 it is working fine

Comment: @David, do you have both a local_policy.jar and a US_export_policy.jar in your lib/security directory? Or, is it an option for you to upgrade your JVM?

Comment: @jzheaux I tried on a different machine which was having  jdk1.8.0_171 and it worked there. Both local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar is available in both versions of JDK.

Comment: If you would like to provide a github sample that reproduces the issue, I'd be happy to take a look.